# Adding alt tag to image in a rich text field via its Edit button, within a matrix - breaks code link to the image

Tags: matrix, image, richtext

Craft 2.4. Unusual bug. Adding an alt tag to an image within a rich text field via its Edit button, that's in a matrix, works just fine the first time the entry is saved. However, re-saving the entry breaks the code to the image.

This:

img alt="test" src="/resources/images/someimage.png#asset:1844:url"

Becomes this:

img alt="test" resources="" images="" someimage.png#asset:1844:url"=""

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you're on the latest release.  In [2.4.2670](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2670), we updated Redactor to the latest so that might have fixed some bugs.
2. I can't reproduce what you're seeing. The modal that comes up from the Redactor edit image button doesn't have an "alt" field, so I'm not sure where you're seeing that.
3. If view source and manually add the alt tag, it behaves as expected no matter how many times I save/edit the entry.
4. Bug reports are better off [here](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285224-bugs). :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a Redactor bug. See the last line of the 10.2 changelog: "In Firefox when a title was added to an image, it received improper empty tags". Craft currently contains Redactor 10.1.3

http://imperavi.com/redactor/log/

**Update:**

This has been fixed for the next (post [2.4.2670](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2670)) release.